# Why is length of Ethernet Type field 2 bytes?

Tags: frame, ethernet

There are few types of Ethernet but then also we have 2 bytes for Ethernet Type in the frame structure. Is this not a wastage of space by under utilization of space? I mean is 1 byte not enough to fit all the possibilities of Ethernet Types or is it some other reason?

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason is that those 2 bytes could be the payload length if LLC  encapsulation.  if length only 1 byte, then it's too small.

Also from the perspective of byte alignment, all fields (except payload) are at least 16 bit  aligned.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bit over 200 ethertypes used based on a rough eyeball of https://www.iana.org/assignments/ieee-802-numbers/ieee-802-numbers.xhtml so using only 8 bits could be a bit tight. A number of entries in that table cover a range of EtherTypes as well so the actual allocated number is probably higher (I haven't actually counted).

I don't know anything about the thinking at the time, presumably they didn't know how many EtherTypes would be used, but it looks like using two bytes was the right decisions. It's worth bearing in mind that whilst today IP is very dominant so there are probably only a handful of EtherTypes in common usage, that wasn't the case at the time and they couldn't have been confident it would be the case going forward.

As a more minor point, at ethernet speeds (it started at about 3Mb/s) one byte isn't a huge deal.

Answer (score -1):

Look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethertype. It's protocol definition of that frame

Comment: I know it is the definition but is that not wastage of space? I want to know some logical reason behind this.